# Where can I read about the techniques for computing areas and volumes before calculus?

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I've read the following [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus#History_of_differentiation):

> The key insight, however, that earned them this credit, was the fundamental theorem of calculus relating differentiation and integration: this rendered obsolete most previous methods for computing areas and volumes.

I'd like to read something that explains how it was before calculus and what changes have been made after calculus. Can you point me to some book or article about it?

Comment: See [method of exhaustion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion) and [Cavalieri's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri's_principle).

Comment: Fermat had a nice method for $x^{p/q}$, where $p/q\ne -1$. In general, looking under *quadrature* will give useful hits.

Comment: Volumes were usually calculated with displacement of water. It wasn't very accurate and provided no insight onto derivation but was enough for the non mathematician.